# Python : Input an answer and receive a response that is randomly given on a list of responses

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i want to accomplish is when you input a letter and if the letter is correct there will be an automatic response that it was correct but it will not be the same response every time a letter of the correct answer inputted.

I made a list of responses and placed a random function for the list

```
reaction=['good job','lucky guess!',you\'re on a roll]
react=random.choice(reaction)
```

I tried placing it after the

```
for letter in rand:
rand_list.append(letter)
```

but this is not what I want because what this does is it gives the same response over and over again on each correct letter you input and would change at the next word that you'll be guessing.

The complete code is:

```
import random

alphabeth = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
rand_list = []
guessed_list = []

def prepWord():
    global rand, guessed_list, blank, rand_list,good,react_good
    react_good = ['Good job!', 'Lucky guess!', 'Took you a while to guess that letter!', 'You\'re on a roll!']

    words = ['note', 'pencil', 'paper','foo']
    rand = random.choice(words)
    guessed_list = []
    blank = ['_']*len(rand)
    rand_list = []
    for letter in rand:
        rand_list.append(letter)

    startPlay()

def startPlay():
    print('Welcome to Hangman. You have 8 tires to guess the secret word.')
    gameQ = input('Ready to play Hangman? y or n: ')
    if gameQ == 'y' or gameQ == 'Y':
        print('Guess the letters:')
        print(blank)
        checkAnswer()
    elif gameQ == 'n' or gameQ == 'N':
        print('goodbye')
        print('*********************')

    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Please try again')
        startPlay()


def playAgain():
    again = input('Would you like to play again? y or n --> ')
    if again == 'y':
        prepWord()
    elif again == 'n':
        print('Thanks for playing')
    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Please type y or n only')
        print(' ')
        playAgain()

def checkAnswer():
    tries = 0
    x = True
    while x:
        answer = input('').lower()
        if answer not in guessed_list:
            guessed_list.append(answer)
            if len(answer)>1:
                print('One letter at a time.')

            elif answer not in alphabeth:
                print('Invalid character, please try again.')
            else:
                if answer in rand:
                    print("The letter {} is in the word.".format(answer))

                    indices = [b for b, letter in enumerate(rand_list) if letter == answer]
                    for b in indices:
                        blank[b] = answer
                        print (blank)

                else:
                    print ("I'm sorry the letter {} is not in the word. Please try again.".format(answer))
                    tries +=1
                    if tries
                    if tries == 8:
                        print('Game over. You are out of tries')
                        playAgain()
        else:
            print('Letter {} already used. Try another.'.format(answer))

        if '_' not in blank:
            print('You guessed the secret word. You win!')
            final_word = 'The secret word is '
            for letter in blank:
                final_word += letter.upper()
            print(final_word)
            print('')
            x = False
            playAgain()



prepWord()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call random each time you want a new message. Calling it once and saving the result means your `react` variable never changes. The following defines the reaction list at the top for easy editing, but has this line in `checkAnswer()` that calls random.choice every time a correct letter is entered `print(random.choice(reaction))`.

```
import random

alphabeth = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
rand_list = []
guessed_list = []
reaction=["good job","lucky guess!","you're on a roll"]

def prepWord():
    global rand, guessed_list, blank, rand_list,good,react_good
    react_good = ['Good job!', 'Lucky guess!', 'Took you a while to guess that letter!', 'You\'re on a roll!']

    words = ['note', 'pencil', 'paper','foo']
    rand = random.choice(words)
    guessed_list = []
    blank = ['_']*len(rand)
    rand_list = []
    for letter in rand:
        rand_list.append(letter)

    startPlay()

def startPlay():
    print('Welcome to Hangman. You have 8 tires to guess the secret word.')
    gameQ = input('Ready to play Hangman? y or n: ')
    if gameQ == 'y' or gameQ == 'Y':
        print('Guess the letters:')
        print(blank)
        checkAnswer()
    elif gameQ == 'n' or gameQ == 'N':
        print('goodbye')
        print('*********************')

    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Please try again')
        startPlay()


def playAgain():
    again = input('Would you like to play again? y or n --> ')
    if again == 'y':
        prepWord()
    elif again == 'n':
        print('Thanks for playing')
    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Please type y or n only')
        print(' ')
        playAgain()

def checkAnswer():
    tries = 0
    x = True
    while x:
        answer = input('').lower()
        if answer not in guessed_list:
            guessed_list.append(answer)
            if len(answer)>1:
                print('One letter at a time.')

            elif answer not in alphabeth:
                print('Invalid character, please try again.')
            else:
                if answer in rand:
                    print("The letter {} is in the word.".format(answer))
                    print(random.choice(reaction))
                    indices = [b for b, letter in enumerate(rand_list) if letter == answer]
                    for b in indices:
                        blank[b] = answer
                        print (blank)

                else:
                    print ("I'm sorry the letter {} is not in the word. Please try again.".format(answer))
                    tries +=1
                    if tries == 8:
                        print('Game over. You are out of tries')
                        playAgain()
        else:
            print('Letter {} already used. Try another.'.format(answer))

        if '_' not in blank:
            print('You guessed the secret word. You win!')
            final_word = 'The secret word is '
            for letter in blank:
                final_word += letter.upper()
            print(final_word)
            print('')
            x = False
            playAgain()



prepWord()
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote some of your code. I'm posting it here so hopefully looking at the difference will be helpful to you. Some of the changes are:

1. No recursion: while it can be very powerful, it's usually safer to use a loop. For example in `startPlay()` every time the user enters an invalid character you open another nested `startPlay()` function. This could lead to many nested functions loaded at once. Worse `startPlay()` can call `checkAnswer()` which can call `playAgain()` which can call `prepWord()` which can call `startPlay()`. The longer the user plays, the more memory your program will take. It will eventually crash.
2. No global variables that change. While defining global variables at the top of the script can be useful, calling `globals` and editing them in a function is risky and makes your code harder to debug and reuse. It's better to pass what is needed from function to function. Some might argue against defining any variables at the top, but I find it useful. Especially if someone else will customize the details, but does not need to understand how the code works.
3. Some details working with lists and strings are different. You don't need to define the alphabet, that already exists as [string.ascii_lowercase](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html). You can check for characters in a string directly with the equivalent of `if 'p' in 'python':` so you never have to convert the chosen word into a list. You can covert lists back to strings with `join` like `" ".join(blank)` which converts `blank` from a list to a string with a space between each element of `blank`. Using a different string before the `join` would change the character inserted between each element.

I hope this helps you. You can do whatever you want with this code:

```
import random
import string

# Global and on top for easy editing, not changed in any function
words = ['note', 'pencil', 'paper','foo']
react_good = ["Good job!", 
              "Lucky guess!", 
              "Took you a while to guess that letter!", 
              "You're on a roll!"]


def game():
    games = 0
    while start(games):  # Checks if they want to play.
        games += 1
        play_game()


def play_game():  # returns True if won and returns False if lost.
    rand_word = random.choice(words)  # Choose the word to use.
    blank = ['_']*len(rand_word)
    guessed = []
    tries = 0
    while True:  # Not infinite, ends when a return statement is called

        print("")
        print(" ".join(blank))  # Converting to string first looks better
        answer = input('Guess a letter: ').strip().lower()  # remove whitespace

        if answer == 'exit' or answer == 'quit':
            return False  # Exit Game
        elif len(answer) != 1:
            print('One letter at a time.')
        elif answer not in string.ascii_lowercase:  # same as alphabet string
            print('Invalid character, please try again.')
        elif answer in guessed:
            print('Letter {} already used. Try another.'.format(answer))
        elif answer in rand_word:  # Correct Guess
            # Update progress
            indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(rand_word) if x == answer]
            for i in indices:
                blank[i] = answer
            # Check if they have won
            if blank == list(rand_word):  # Or could convert blank to a string
                print('You guessed the secret word. You win!')
                print('The secret word is ' + rand_word.upper())
                print('')
                return True  # Exit Game
            guessed.append(answer)
            print("The letter {} is in the word.".format(answer))
            print(random.choice(react_good))
        else:  # Incorrect Guess
            tries += 1
            # Check if they have lost.
            if tries >= 8:
                print('Game over. You are out of tries')
                return False  # Exit Game
            print ("I'm sorry the letter {} is not in the word. Please try again.".format(answer))
            guessed.append(answer)


def start(games = 0):  # Gives different messages for first time
    if games == 0:  # If first time
        print('Welcome to Hangman. You have 8 tires to guess the secret word.')

    # Loops until they give a valid answer and a return statement is called
    while True:  
        # Get answer
        if games > 0:  # or just 'if games' works too
            game_q = input('Would you like to play again? y or n --> ')
        else:
            game_q = input('Ready to play Hangman? y or n: ')

        # Check answer
        if game_q.lower() == 'y':
            return True
        elif game_q.lower() == 'n':
            if games > 0:
                print('Thanks for playing')
            else:
                print('goodbye')
                print('*********************')
            return False
        else:
            print('Invalid answer. Please try again')


game()
```

Comment: thank you @KyleV for your help. I'm trying to study your code and try if I can make a version of mine. I just have a question though. If the correct and wrong guesses stores inside guessed=[ ] why did you have to place guessed.append(answer) twice?

Comment: I did not add answers to `guessed` until after they are checked to be valid. The statement to append is there twice because both correct and incorrect answers are added, one statement for each. I didn't put it before the long if/elif/else block so that answers that are too long or not letters are not stored in guessed. This means `guessed` has to stay small and repeated incorrect attempts keep getting the message telling them what they are doing wrong. So a second guess of 'ab' would get the 'One letter at a time message' instead of the 'Letter ab already used. Try another' message.

Comment: While my code in the answer does solve your original question, my first answer is probably the better one to accept.

Comment: how come when I just hit enter without typing a letter it accepts it as a correct answer?

Comment: I've edited it to check for answers of length 0. I just changed the line `elif len(answer) > 1:` to `elif len(answer) != 1:`. I didn't realize this but `'' in 'string'` returns True. So the empty string was accepted as being in the rand_word.